# vgo case-insensitive import collision

Tags: go

I'm trying to use vgo and I'm getting the following error

```
$ vgo build ./...
vgo: resolving import "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
vgo: finding github.com/Sirupsen/logrus (latest)
vgo: adding github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5
../../../mod/github.com/docker/go-events@v0.0.0-20170721190031-9461782956ad/broadcast.go:7:2: case-insensitive import collision: "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" and "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
```

I've tried adding the following to my go.mod file:

```
exclude github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5

require (
    ...
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5
    ...
)
```

and

```
replace github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5 => github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5
```

but then I just get the following:

```
$ vgo build ./...
vgo: resolving import "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
vgo: finding github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.4
vgo: finding github.com/Sirupsen/logrus (latest)
vgo: adding github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.4
vgo: downloading github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.4
../../../mod/github.com/docker/go-events@v0.0.0-20170721190031-9461782956ad/broadcast.go:7:2: case-insensitive import collision: "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" and "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
```

I don't know which package is causing the issue. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's may be a case change issue: Sirupsen versus sirupsen. For example, one of many,

[Rename back to Sirupsen/logrus #570](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/570)

Comment: That's definitely the issue. Dang, wishing vgo was powerful enough to handle this.